# Segmentation fault for c program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I got segmentation fault for the code here.

gdb :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_IO_fgets (buf=0x601080 <rc> "", n=100, fp=0x0) at iofgets.c:50
50  iofgets.c: No such file or directory.
```

Code:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char rc[100];
FILE *fp;
int status;

void main() {    
    fp = popen("sudo lshw |", "grep UUID");
    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("NULL pointer");
    while (fgets(rc, 100, fp) != '\0')
        printf("%s", rc);
    status = pclose(fp);
    if (status == -1) {
        printf("pclose error");
        /* Error reported by pclose() */
    } else{
        printf("Unknown error");
    }
    //return 0;
}
```

null pointer I guess? i tried with solutions given , but not worked. Somehow silly mistake I guess

sorry , the shell command will b `sudo dmidecode | grep UUID`

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete function call-stack when the crash happens. The problem isn't in the library code, it's somewhere in your code.

Comment: Any good reason why your variables are all globals? and I see you declared `void main()` instead of `int main()` which is the right way, and commented `return 0;`.

Comment: I'm guessing you probably want to print that error message *instead* of marching on into read from an invalid file pointer, not *in addition*.

Comment: Also note that [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) returns the buffer (or `NULL`) not a single character.

Comment: I wanted to get result of the system call at popen.

Comment: On many platforms, @JoachimPileborg, `'\0' == NULL` will evaluate true, so the given code has a good likelihood of working in that respect.  You're right, though, that it's poor form.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That `NULL` and `'\0'` happens to be same on some compilers doesn't mean they always will be. `NULL` is a "null"  ***pointer***, and `'\0'` is a ***character***, they are inherently different and comparing those two (if the compiler allows it and doesn't scream at you) will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, You are right that `NULL` and `'\0'` have different types, but the latter has an integer type, and integer types are interconvertible with and comparable with pointer types.  In fact, C specifies that an integer constant with value 0 *is* a null pointer constant, with or without a cast to type `void *`.  So in fact, that part of the OP's code will work reliably on *every* compliant system.  But it's still poor form.

Comment: the code noticed that the open failed and prints a message.  Then it goes right ahead and executes the while loop.  It should exit the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong

```
fp = popen("sudo lshw |", "grep UUID");
```

maybe you mean, read [`popen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)

```
fp = popen("sudo lshw | grep UUID", "r");
```

the call failed, but even though you checked for `fp == NULL`, you continued anyway causing undefined behavior, and leading to the segmentation fault, the `fp == NULL` check needs to abort the program, like this

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {    
    char  rc[100];
    FILE *fp;
    int   status;

    fp = popen("sudo lshw | grep UUID", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("error:%d: %s", errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    while (fgets(rc, 100, fp) != NULL)
        printf("%s", rc);
    status = pclose(fp);
    if (status == -1) {
        printf("error:%d: %s", errno, strerror(errno));
    } else { /* this means no error happened */
        printf("success: pipe, closed.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

note that `main()` shall return an `int`, and as [Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg) commented, `fgets(...) == '\0'` is wrong, `fgets()` returns `NULL` on error and `NULL == '\0'` is not necessarily true.

Also, `pclose()` returns `-1` on error, if it does not return `-1` then everything went as expected.

Comment: The segmentation error gone, but I am not getting the system call result, instead it gave Unknown error which is last printf

Comment: You should not write a c program for this, specially don't use `sudo`, just write a shell script. And to check why the error is happening you could `#include <errno.h>` and check `errno` after `popen()`.

Comment: I need to write a c as I am experimenting with system call, hence it was needed

Comment: surprisingly it didn't fail in lshw but neither printed the value of the buffer.

Comment: @anupam_on I updated the code, but you got `pclose()` wrong too, if it didn't return `-1` then no error happened, note that in your code, no matter what `pclose()` returns you always consider it an error.

Comment: giving warnings and the same thing happened, it is executing command but not giving output

Comment: Execute the command directly, does it work. Maybe the `grep` is wrong, i.e. there is no line containing `UUID`. I tried it with another command and it worked. I used another command because I don't have `sudo` or `lshw`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71107/discussion-between-iharob-and-anupam-on).

Comment: sorry, the mistake was done by me . the command was sudo dmidecode | grep UUID
sorry mate. It worked now :)
remove warnings by making printf("error:%d: %d", errno, strerror(errno)); in your code